# Getting Error on while reading a blank text file?

Tags: vb6

Using VB6

When I Reading the blank text file, showing error as Input Past end of file

Code.

```
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim TS As TextStream
Dim TempS As String
Dim Final As String
Set fso = New FileSystemObject
Set TS = fso.OpenTextFile(txtSourceDatabaseFile & "\" & FileName, ForReading)
Final = TS.ReadAll
Do Until TS.AtEndOfStream
    TempS = TS.ReadLine
    Final = Final & TempS & vbCrLf
Loop
TS.Close
```

How to check whether the text file is empty or not? If empty no need to read the contents, else it should read contents.

Need VB6 code Help

Comment: Which line does it fall over on?

Comment: Also worth checking for existance of file before attempting to open. I think its Dir(filename) = "" if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're doing this:

```
Final = TS.ReadAll
Do Until TS.AtEndOfStream
    TempS = TS.ReadLine
    Final = Final & TempS & vbCrLf
Loop
```

You should check for AtEndOfStream before calling ReadAll, something like:

```
If TS.AtEndOfStream Then
   Final = ""
Else
    Final = TS.ReadAll
    Do Until TS.AtEndOfStream
        TempS = TS.ReadLine
        Final = Final & TempS & vbCrLf
    Loop
End If
```

As a note though, you've got a logic error in there: ReadAll will read the entire file into memory. So subsequently calling ReadLine will return nothing. Either use ReadAll and parse the input with string manipulation, or call ReadLine exclusively. Don't use both.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to read a text file into a string, Stefan [answered that on one of your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199143/how-to-display-the-text-file-while-clicking-the-button/1199576#1199576) in July. The answer is still the same.

```
strFilename = "C:\1.txt"
iFile = FreeFile
Open strFilename For Input As #iFile
strTheData = StrConv(InputB(LOF(iFile), iFile), vbUnicode)
Close #iFile
```

If the file is empty (zero-length), strTheData will contain an empty string "". Alternatively you can check the length of a file with [FileLen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262742(VS.60).aspx).

```
If FileLen("C:\1.txt") = 0 Then MsgBox "Empty file"
```

I recommend avoiding FileSystemObject: it's sometimes missing on user's machines - possibly because over zealous IT departments are scared of viruses? EDIT: in fact I've just heard from my colleagues about a user problem last week that turned out to be a FileSystemObject problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check file size, you could ask for `.Size` property directly, without opening that file:

```
set folder = fso.GetFolder(path)
for each file in folder.Files
  Response.Write file.Name & ": " & file.Size & "<br>"
Next
```