# How to get DateTime stamp of a textfile using VB 6

Tags: vb6

How do you obtain the DateTime stamp of a textfile using VB 6.0? By DateTime stamp I mean the date & time the textfile was created or modified. Sample code would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

For created/last modified you can simply;

```
dateVar = FileDateTime("c:\foo\bar\qux.file")
```

Comment: This works and is simpler than using the FileSystemObject from the scripting run time. Thanks Alex

Comment: Nice.  I was not aware that function existed.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `GetFile` method in `FileSystemObject` and then just use the `DateCreated` and 'DateLastModified' properties of it.

Here's the documentation with a sample for how to do it from VBscript (pretty much the same from VB6):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sheydkke%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You want the FileSystemObject from the scripting run time.

MS gives an [example of getting the creation time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ft05taf(v=VS.85).aspx)

Note that example works in VBScript as well in VB6 you can get the file by
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716288(VS.60).aspx

ie

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject, fil As File
Set fil = fso.GetFile("c:\test.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

[Dev X : get datetime in VB6](http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18982)