# how to check whether Scripting Runtime is available

Tags: vba

Is there any way in `VBA` to determine whether the `Scripting-Runtime` aka `scrrun.dll` is disabled on a users system ([here's a link on how to do that](https://martin77s.wordpress.com/2018/05/09/disabling-the-scripting-filesystemobject-comobject/))?

I know, this is a very rare case, but it could be the case for exactly one client. There is another thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845797/is-using-the-windows-scripting-runtime-especially-the-filesystemobject-thereof) but it's a little different.

Would you just go something like this?

```
Dim fso As Object

On Error Resume Next
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
On Error Goto 0

If fso Is Nothing then _
  MsgBox "Scripting runtime is not available on this system."
```

Comment: This customer has the Scripting library disabled but Office installed? I am not sure if this makes sense...

Comment: I'm not at all a sophisticated programmer, more like a scientist which was the chosen one to write the VBA-stuff, so you're right and I'm probably totally wrong. But the debugger stops execution at the line where I check whether the script was started from a mapped drive via [this](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?850527-How-can-I-obtain-the-UNC-path-for-a-Mapped-drive&s=b06f5c39a030b72859431d85b3cc9a50&p=5193341&viewfull=1#post5193341) approach . Since I see no other reason for failure (and it runs fine on every other machine) this was my suspect and at least now I know how to check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I would use this approach, it's as short as it can be:

```vb
Public Function ScriptingRuntimeAvailable() As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"): End With

    ScriptingRuntimeAvailable = Err.Number = 0
End Function
```

Comment: thank you! and I thought my solution was already short ...

Comment: @JohnDoe: You're welcome. Please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you find that it solved your problem.

Comment: sorry, I thought upvoting would do