# Read a text file and then add all lines to list box in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a text file in my desktop...

In this file we have five lines:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
```

If the user choose this text file then  all lines (five lines) add to list box items.

For example, we have these in the list box (when the user choose the text file (which it has five lines)):

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
```

Comment: [This question has already been answered.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579333/loading-text-from-a-file-into-a-textbox

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\dir\file.txt")
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(lines)
```

[More information is at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Or even shorter: `ListBox1.Items.AddRange(IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\dir\file.txt"))`

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub OpenList()
    Dim openfile = New OpenFileDialog()
    openfile.Filter = "Text (*.txt)|*.txt"
    If (openfile.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
        Dim myfile As String = openfile.FileName
        Dim allLines As String() = File.ReadAllLines(myfile)
        For Each line As String In allLines
            listBox.Items.Add(line)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: He asked for VB.NET so I converted your code for you. Next time be sensitive to this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Dim openfile = New OpenFileDialog() With {.Filter = "Text (*.Text)|*.txt"}
If (openfile.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
    For Each line As String In File.ReadAllLines(openfile.FileName)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(line)
    Next
End If
```

Code is a lot better.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Consider expanding a bit and explaining what the code does - a block of code with no explanation won't really help the asker in the future.

Comment: Thanks. I just posted this because it was a much easier code to read compared to the code that was posted above. Will do next time.