# Read file into TextBox and write TextBox content to a file

Tags: vb.net

How can I write the text in a `TextBox` to a file when a `Button` is clicked. Then how can I read from the file into the TextBox.

Comment: Sounds like a great plan.  Get back to us when you have a question.  Manwwhile, read: [ASk]

Comment: Question is too broad. Can you show some code of what you've already tried and detail where you're encountering an error or issue?

Comment: As mentioned above please search SO, code by yourself and don't hesitate asking again here. Ok - we have some rules here ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [How to write textbox values to .txt file with vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002529/how-to-write-textbox-values-to-txt-file-with-vb-net)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Read a text file then add all lines to list box in vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20290084/read-a-text-file-then-add-all-lines-to-list-box-in-vb-net)