# How can I split these text files?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I need to make a program that reads text files and then these need to be split. I guess my split function isn't working.

The intention is that all text from the file needs to be split and displayed in a `ListBox1`. If there are some weird things in my code, that is because I tried a lot, but nothing worked.

Code:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim objFile As New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\Users\klaasjelle\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Opdrachtje\Opdrachtje\bin\Debug\Images.txt")
        Dim strTextFile As String
        strTextFile = objFile.ReadLine

        Dim somestring As String() = Split(",")
        Dim somestring2() As String
        somestring2 = TextBox1.Text.Split(",")

        Dim text As String
        For i = 0 To UBound(somestring2) - 1
            text = strTextFile & " - "(somestring2(i))
        Next i

        Do Until strTextFile Is Nothing
            ListBox1.Items.Add(text)
            strTextFile = objFile.ReadLine()

        Loop
        objFile.Close()
         objFile.Dispose()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Here are a couple of lines in the `Images.txt` file.

```
N:\Opdrachten\2363-3255-01\0 - Origineel Kleur\2017-03-08\00000001.tif,1,268432
N:\Opdrachten\2363-3255-01\0 - Origineel Binair\2017-03-08\00000001.tif,1,17560
N:\Opdrachten\2363-3255-01\0 - Origineel Kleur\2017-03-08\00000002.tif,1,264276
N:\Opdrachten\2363-3255-01\0 - Origineel Binair\2017-03-08\00000002.tif,1,15706
N:\Opdrachten\2363-3255-01\0 - Origineel Kleur\2017-03-08\00000003.tif,1,263212
N:\Opdrachten\2363-3255-01\0 - Origineel Binair\2017-03-08\00000003.tif,1,16836
N:\Opdrachten\2363-3255-01\0 - Origineel Kleur\2017-03-08\00000004.tif,1,261722
N:\Opdrachten\2363-3255-01\0 - Origineel Binair\2017-03-08\00000004.tif,1,16786
N:\Opdrachten\2363-3255-01\0 - Origineel Kleur\2017-03-08\00000005.tif,1,268062
N:\Opdrachten\2363-3255-01\0 - Origineel Binair\2017-03-08\00000005.tif,1,18514
N:\Opdrachten\2363-3255-01\0 - Origineel Kleur\2017-03-08\00000006.tif,1,250534
N:\Opdrachten\2363-3255-01\0 - Origineel Binair\2017-03-08\00000006.tif,1,15536
N:\Opdrachten\2363-3255-01\0 - Origineel Kleur\2017-03-08\00000007.tif,1,249188
N:\Opdrachten\2363-3255-01\0 - Origineel Binair\2017-03-08\00000007.tif,1,15280
N:\Opdrachten\2363-3255-01\0 - Origineel Kleur\2017-03-08\00000008.tif,1,255074
N:\Opdrachten\2363-3255-01\0 - Origineel Binair\2017-03-08\00000008.tif,1,16324
N:\Opdrachten\2363-3255-01\0 - Origineel Kleur\2017-03-08\00000009.tif,1,277774
N:\Opdrachten\2363-3255-01\0 - Origineel Binair\2017-03-08\00000009.tif,1,18174
N:\Opdrachten\2363-3255-01\0 - Origineel Kleur\2017-03-08\00000010.tif,1,260760
N:\Opdrachten\2363-3255-01\0 - Origineel Binair\2017-03-08\00000010.tif,1,17212
N:\Opdrachten\2363-3255-01\0 - Origineel Kleur\2017-03-08\00000011.tif,1,257688
N:\Opdrachten\2363-3255-01\0 - Origineel Binair\2017-03-08\00000011.tif,1,16332
N:\Opdrachten\2363-3255-01\0 - Origineel Kleur\2017-03-08\00000012.tif,1,265722
N:\Opdrachten\2363-3255-01\0 - Origineel Binair\2017-03-08\00000012.tif,1,16610
N:\Opdrachten\2363-3255-01\0 - Origineel Kleur\2017-03-08\00000013.tif,1,265530
N:\Opdrachten\2363-3255-01\0 - Origineel Binair\2017-03-08\00000013.tif,1,18016
N:\Opdrachten\2363-3255-01\0 - Origineel Kleur\2017-03-08\00000014.tif,1,259384
N:\Opdrachten\2363-3255-01\0 - Origineel Binair\2017-03-08\00000014.tif,1,16698
N:\Opdrachten\2363-3255-01\0 - Origineel Kleur\2017-03-08\00000015.tif,1,255404
N:\Opdrachten\2363-3255-01\0 - Origineel Binair\2017-03-08\00000015.tif,1,16014
N:\Opdrachten\2363-3255-01\0 - Origineel Kleur\2017-03-08\00000016.tif,1,276840
N:\Opdrachten\2363-3255-01\0 - Origineel Binair\2017-03-08\00000016.tif,1,17198
N:\Opdrachten\2363-3255-01\0 - Origineel Kleur\2017-03-08\00000017.tif,1,279526
N:\Opdrachten\2363-3255-01\0 - Origineel Binair\2017-03-08\00000017.tif,1,16774
N:\Opdrachten\2363-3255-01\0 - Origineel Kleur\2017-03-08\00000018.tif,1,262920
N:\Opdrachten\2363-3255-01\0 - Origineel Binair\2017-03-08\00000018.tif,1,17132
N:\Opdrachten\2363-3255-01\0 - Origineel Kleur\2017-03-08\00000019.tif,1,266274
N:\Opdrachten\2363-3255-01\0 - Origineel Binair\2017-03-08\00000019.tif,1,16418
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking.  Could you show a sample of your text file and what you'd like the output to look like?

Comment: you are splitting the content of the textbox1 when you didn't add anything to it: `somestring2 = TextBox1.Text.Split(",")`

Comment: `Dim somestring As String() = Split(",")` what is this line meant to do in your code? Because it isn't used anywhere and you aren't splitting anything with it...

Comment: Please specify how the file looks so we can help and look into the [String.Split()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: `Dim text As String
    For i = 0 To UBound(somestring2) - 1
        text = strTextFile & " - "(somestring2(i))
    Next i`  this section. you are reassigning `text` each time you loop through so text will only ever be the last item in the `somestring2`. Also you are looping `srtTextFile` yet it is declared as a string not a string array.

Comment: Also look into reading in your file this way, as not sure you are using `StreamReader` correctly. [System.IO.File.ReadAllLines Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) this will be easier.

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20290084/read-a-text-file-and-then-add-all-lines-to-list-box-in-vb-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, turn [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx):

> Restricts implicit data type conversions to only widening conversions, disallows late binding, and disallows implicit typing that results in an Object type.

Some of your code would produce a compile error with **Option Strict On**. It's good practice to *always* have this setting on.

Secondly, consider implementing [Using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx):

> Managed resources are disposed of by the .NET Framework garbage collector (GC) without any extra coding on your part. You do not need a Using block for managed resources. However, you can still use a Using block to force the disposal of a managed resource instead of waiting for the garbage collector.

Now onto the problem at hand. I believe you want to split the lines of text up using a comma (`,`). As an example:

```
N:\Opdrachten\2363-3255-01\0 - Origineel Kleur\2017-03-08\00000001.tif,1,268432
```

Would become:

```
N:\Opdrachten\2363-3255-01\0 - Origineel Kleur\2017-03-08\00000001.tif
1
268432
```

And you then want to display this in a `ListBox`.

*If* I am correct in that assumption then I would first advise to use a [ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview(v=vs.110).aspx) as you can display the information a little neater. Add 3 columns to your `ListView` and set the `View` property to **Details**.

The following code will split each line up and add it to the `ListView`:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Using sr As New System.IO.StreamReader(filename)

        While Not sr.EndOfStream

            Dim lines As String() = sr.ReadLine.Split(New String() {","}, StringSplitOptions.None)

            Dim lvItem As New ListViewItem(lines(0))
            lvItem.SubItems.Add(lines(1))
            lvItem.SubItems.Add(lines(2))

            ListView1.Items.Add(lvItem)

        End While

    End Using

    ListView1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent)
    ListView1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize)

End Sub
```

This is a screenshot of the output:

[image]

Obviously you would want to give a better name for each `ColumnHeader` but this should give you something to go on.

As I'm not 100% on your desired output I'll also provide a solution for your `ListBox` and only display the first part. It's similar to the `ListView` solution:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Using sr As New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\Images.txt")

        While Not sr.EndOfStream

            Dim lines As String() = sr.ReadLine.Split(New String() {","}, StringSplitOptions.None)

            ListBox1.Items.Add(lines(0))

        End While

    End Using

End Sub
```

This is a screenshot of the output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, the first method you mentioned with the listview helped.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser class from 'Microsoft.VisualBasic' assembly to parse you file as CSV file, in c# like:

```
 var header = new List<string>();
 var data = new List<string[]>();

     var line = 0;
     using (var parser = new TextFieldParser(filePathOrStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    parser.CommentTokens = new string[] { "#" };
                    parser.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
                    parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

                    try
                    {
                        while (!parser.EndOfData)
                        {
                            string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
                            if (line == 0)
                            {
                                header.AddRange(fields);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                data.Add(fields);
                            }
                            line++;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (MalformedLineException mfex)
                    {
                        // error handler
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

1st thing I would suggest is to always puth filepaths into their own variables, this makes code easier to read and to change in the future.

As said in comments, also look into reading in your file this way, as not sure you were using StreamReader correctly. [System.IO.File.ReadAllLines Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) this will be easier.

I've left comments in code to help

This should help get you started:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

dim filepath as String = "C:\Users\klaasjelle\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Opdrachtje\Opdrachtje\bin\Debug\Images.txt"
Dim objFile as List(of String) = New List(Of String)
objFile.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(filepath))
'now have a list with all your file written into it. It is now possible to loop through it later

Dim somestring2 As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)  'something2 needs to be more of a descriptive name as not sure what it's meant for at this stage in reading the code. I also changed this to a list as list are better and easier to use than arrays, though you will have to google why.

'loop through file and read into array.
For Each record as String in objFile 
   somestring2.Add(record.Split(","c))
Next

'you now have a list with everything split down using comma as a delimator.

'Now here you can add to the listbox. I'll leave this for you to do as the file has been read in correctly now.

End Sub
```